# ¿como hago para que este switch me vuelva a enviar un menú de opciones cuando el case sea default?

Tags: java, menú, switch

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
       int opcion,esw=0;
                   opcion=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese una opcion \n1.evaluar contraseña"
                           + "\n2.salir"));
                   
                   switch(opcion){
                       case 1:String psw  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese contraseña:");
           CheckPsw value = new CheckPsw();
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, value.check(psw));
                       
                       case 2:JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"proceso finalizado");;
                       default:
                   
                   }
   }
}
```

colegas, como le hago para que, cuando ponga un numero diferente del 1 o el 2 en el switch, me vuelva a enviar este menú de opciones?:

```
opcion=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese una opcion \n1.evaluar contraseña"
                           + "\n2.salir"));
```

Answer (score 0):

usando do while puedes hacer eso,te recomiendo usar System.exit(0) en el case 2 despues del mensaje del Joptionpane,de esa manera cerraras el programa

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
               int opcion,esw=0;
               do{
                           opcion=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese una opcion \n1.evaluar contraseña"
                                   + "\n2.salir"));
                           
                           switch(opcion){
                               case 1:String psw  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese contraseña:");
                   CheckPsw value = new CheckPsw();
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, value.check(psw));
                               break;        
                               case 2:JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"proceso finalizado");
                               System.exit(0);
                               break;
                               default:
                               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Opcion Incorrecta");
                           
                           }
           }while(opcion!=2||opcion!=1);
        }
        
        }
```